# How to create a login API using microsoft azure and passport js

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, passport.js, azure-active-directory

I am presently working on an App , which has its backend services in azure ( database + server ) . The database here is MS SQL .I am supposed to write an API for login in NodeJS .

Since I am new to the field of programming and web development, I am totally unable to figure this out ?

I am also supposed to use Azure Active Directory ....

Comment: did you search for the documentation in msdn??https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD not only provides authenticate, it also is a user provider. If you want to integrate Azure AD in your application, the authentication users via Azure AD should be in your Azure AD tenant, and also be stored by Azure.

So, generally speaking, you can use Azure AD to authenticate your users, and use [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) to manage your users in your AD tenant.

For integrating Azure AD in node.js application via passportjs, besides the document on the Azure site https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/ provided by @Aravind. You also can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect/ for the code sample on Azure, or leverage [passport-azure-ad-oauth2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2) strategy.

For manage your users in your AD tenant, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-node-graphapi-oauth2-0-access/ for the code sample on Azure,

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.